# Download a changing filename from internet

Tags: powershell

I have a working PowerShell script to download a file from the internet.

My issue is files that have changing file names do not work after the file is updated or changed.  How can I modify my script to just have it download the file regardless of the name?

Example Script:

```psh
$url1 = "http://www.tukui.org/downloads/elvui-7.99.zip" <-- Versions Change
$path1 = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Elvui.zip"
Invoke-WebRequest $url1 -OutFile $path1
```

Comment: If directory listing were allowed, you could retrieve the list first, parse the filename out of it, and then download the file. Since directory listings seem to be disabled, you're out of luck.

Comment: No way to do this, for the reasons Ansgar explains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can
This tukui.org have a git repository you can be always up-to date by downloading the following file.

http://git.tukui.org/Elv/elvui/repository/archive.zip

you can check also 
http://www.tukui.org/dl.php